# How to control CSS of h2 inside an unordered list

Tags: css

I'm having a hard time figuring out on how can I control the style of my h2 inside an unordered list. So my structure is like this:

```
<div name="main_div">
    <ul>
        <li><h2>Hello World!</h2></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On my css, what I've got so far is this:

```
.main_div ul li h2 {color:#fff}
```

The thing is, it doesnt change the h2's color. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div name="main_div">

.main_div ul li h2 {color:#fff}
```

`div` elements do not have a `name` attribute – and even if they did, `.main_div` would not select a element by name.

Use a class or an id.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute is not the same as the `class` attribute. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) for documentation.

http://jsbin.com/yimayaseni/1/edit?html,css,output

Change to:

```
<div class="main_div">
    <ul>
        <li><h2>Hello World!</h2></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is correct but your HTML is not. Use this:

```
<div class="main_div">
    <ul>
        <li><h2>Hello World!</h2></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Only the Class attributes are referred when you use the `.class` selector in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [Css Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

you need to select your div by the name attribute:

```css
div[name="main_div"] ul li h2 {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div name="main_div">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS rule will target any h2 element contained within a UL element.

```
ul h2 {
    //Your  CSS
}
```

ul > li makes your selection more specific as it will only select elements which are contained within in an li element which is contained within ul.

```
ul > li h2 {
    //Your CSS
}
```